# Dynamics CRM SDK for .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

This is a duplicate, see [Dynamics CRM/365 SDK and .NET Standard / .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961450/dynamics-crm-365-sdk-and-net-standard-net-core)

A [good question raised by MattHoffmann on MSDN](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24db3a06-c3f8-4953-ac5c-feeb8236c983/dynamics-crm-sdk-for-net-core?forum=crmdevelopment).

**"Is there any information on the Dynamics SDK being compatible with .NET Core? This library is our last roadblock for moving fully into .NET Core.
Thank You"**

^ I'm curious about the level of support as well and it sounds like partners are keen to use it in their solutions.

Comment: see [other response related to Dynamics CRM/365 SDK and .NET Standard / .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075329/4614363)

Comment: It does, apologies for the delay All.