# Dynamics CRM/365 SDK and .NET Standard / .NET Core

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Do you know are there any plans from product group to rewrite CRM SDK libraries into .NET Core or probably just make them .NET Standard compliant?

More and more systems and components treats .NET Standard as a standard :)

I know that we may make the current version (9.x.x) work "somehow" with the .NET Core projects but for some environments it is real pain in the ass.

And I'm asking about official new version and support from product group.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post this on GitHub or MS forums?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I contacted the owners of the [Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/) NuGet package today and got this response:

> We support .net core and .net standard clients connecting to and utilizing our web API.
>
> We are evaluating .net core/standard for the future, However we have no short term plan to move over to .net Core\ .net standard for our SDK Libs.
>
> The truth of it is that 90%+ of our SDK logins are based on WCF/WS-TRUST and UserPassword Based flows.
>
> The teams have provided part of the WCF Support we requested, however WS-Trust has not been adopted going forward in the .net core / standard libs, nor has the UserPasswordFlows that the majority of our population use via connection strings and direct logins.
>
> I expect that your teams ask Is based on being able to use the object model and the patterns that we support in the .net SDK and possible the authentication and logging support we provide in it.
>
> We are working though it with the support of various teams.

---

**Update 1**

A preview of the .NET Core assemblies is now available. See [Announcing the .net Core SDK for Common Data Service (CDS) - External Client Development](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Component-Framework/Announcing-the-net-Core-SDK-for-Common-Data-Service-CDS-External/m-p/470035/highlight/true#M1745).